# error with frame work

Tags: iphone, frameworks, flickr, ios-frameworks

[image]

1) when i am downloading the file from net my frameworks are getting in redcolor font.i cant run that app.pleasetell how to come out of this problem.
2)i downloaded the file for Integrating flickr in my app .and please give sites for objective flicker

Comment: Edit your question to make it more helpful and more likely to receive a proper answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sampleapikey.h(file missing) is a problem.downloaded code ios version is differ from your current ios version thats why framework color is red.